# how can remove auto generated <jsonObject> from the json to xml converter

Tags: wso2-esb

I am working on POC. I send json request`{"a": "abc","test": "testing"}`
and added property in WSO2ESB`<property name="messageType" value="text/xml" scope="axis2"/>`

It will auto generate the POX but added `<jsonObject>`.like that `<jsonObject><a><test></test></a></jsonObject>`
I want to generate pox without `<jsonObject>` .like that `<a><test></test>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an enrich mediator to remove jsonObject from soap body like below.

```
<enrich>
    <source clone="true" xpath="$body//jsonObject//a"/>
    <target type="body"/>
</enrich>
```

You can add a log mediator after enrich mediator and check the changed body.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: <property name="messageType" value="text/xml" scope="axis2"/>                                                                                                        
                  <enrich>
                     <source clone="true" xpath="/jsonObject/a"/>
                     <target type="body"/>
                  </enrich>
                  <respond/>

Comment: Hi Sachini I have added enrich mediator as i pasted above but it won't remove the jsonObject. Please guide if i did any mistake.

Comment: the xpath which you used inside enrich mediator is configured in a wrong way . xpath should be xpath="$body//jsonObject//a"

Comment: <source clone="true" xpath="$body//jsonObject//a"/>. Thanks i have corrected but the jsonObject is still persist.out put is pasted below

Comment: <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap./envelope/" xmlns:cour="http://www.test.com/CourCata.xsd">
    <soapenv:Header><wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" mlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" soap:mustUnderstand="1"><wsse:UsernameToken><wsse:Username>a</wsse:Username> <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/0100401--1.0#PasswordText">a</wsse:Password></wsse:UsernameToken> </wsse:Security></soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body> <jsonObject><CatalogCoursePublishRequest>

Comment: It sounds good. If my answer helps you then you can accept it as the correct answer

Comment: One more thing Sachini if i want to add prefix cour:a like that <cour:a> in the output after removing jsonObject so what should i do.

Comment: Please follow below steps

Comment: 1) create a xslt file named sample.xslt like below

Comment: (***Part1**)<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"; version="2.0"> <xsl:output indent="yes"/> <xsl:strip-space elements=""/> <!--match all the nodes and attributes--> <xsl:template match="node()|@"> <xsl:copy> <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"> </xsl:apply-templates></xsl:copy> </xsl:template>

Comment: (**Part2**)<!--Select the element need to be apply the namespace and prefix --> <xsl:template match="a"> <!--Define the namespace with prefix cour0 --> <xsl:element name="cour0:{name()}" namespace="test.com/test/wso2/blog/Sample">; <!--apply to above selected node--> <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"> </xsl:apply-templates></xsl:element> </xsl:template> </xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: Please add both **Part1** and **Part2** to sample.xslt

Comment: 2) Then Go to Manage-> Service Bus-> Local Entries and add the created sample.xslt file.

Comment: 3) Then in your proxy add xslt mediator as <xslt key="sample.xslt"/> after enrich mediator and add a log mediator after that to check the changed payload

Comment: Following links may help you to create above mentioned scenario

Comment: Adding namespace and prefix to only root tag using XSLT :  **http://www.vitharana.org/2015/01/adding-namespace-and-prefix-to-only.html**

Comment: Add this style sheet (sample.xslt) into local-entries of ESB and it can be referred from XSLT mediator as this: **http://isharapremadasa.blogspot.com/2014/08/wso2-esb-xslt-mediator-writing-simple.html**

Comment: Thanks Sachini i am working on it.once it complete i will inform.

Comment: Hurrah! Again, Thank You Sachini I have implemented the provided solution, it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

The  Tag is added automatically by the esb. There are severa examples how to convert it to xml. See the links below.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Sample+441%3A+Converting+JSON+to+XML+Using+JavaScript
https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Sample+440%3A+Converting+JSON+to+XML+Using+XSLT

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Martin.Actually i have implemented sample 441 as you mentioned with java script. My problem is that i have 37 parameters in the request json and i read it one by one and then put in the desired SOAP format.so i want to transform complete json into soap body automatically and put that soap body in the desired SOAP envelope.                                                    <property name="messageType" value="text/xml" scope="axis2"/>   It will return the SOAP body but with <jsonObject>so i want to remove it.

Comment: I think you should get my point. If you need more clarification please let me know.